# Passing a method as constructor parameter

Tags: c++, methods, constructor

I've been trying to create a new variable of type `Cmplx` (which is my class name) whose data values are 0 and `arg()`(arg being a method of my class)
Thing is that the resulting variable has a value of 0,0.
Is there any work around or am I doing something wrong?

Also, the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <typename vartype>
class Cmplx
{
public:
vartype Re, Im;
Cmplx(vartype const Real, vartype const Imag)//constructor
{
    Re=Real;
    Im=Imag;
}
long double arg()//called method
{
    return atan2(Im,Re);
}
long double abs()
{
    return sqrt(pow(Re,2)+pow(Im,2));
}
Cmplx<long double> log()//target method
{
    Cmplx<long double> IArg(0,arg());
    return IArg+log(abs());
}
Cmplx operator +(Cmplx const param)
{
    Cmplx Tmp;
    Tmp.Im=Im+param.Im;
    Tmp.Re=Re+param.Re;
    return Tmp;
}
Cmplx operator +(vartype const param)
{
    Cmplx Tmp;
    Tmp.Re=Re+param;
    return Tmp;
}
friend Cmplx operator +(vartype const param, Cmplx const para)
{
    Cmplx Tmp;
    Tmp.Re=para.Re+param;
    return Tmp;
}
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &tmp, Cmplx const &param)
{
    tmp<<param.Re<<"+"<<param.Im<<"i";
    return tmp;
}
friend istream& operator >> (istream &tmp, Cmplx &param)
{
    tmp>>param.Re;
    tmp>>param.Im;
    return tmp;
}
};
template <>
class Cmplx<string>
{
public:
Cmplx()
{
    cout << "Are you crazy or something?, a complex NUMBER with LETTERS as real part and imaginary part?"
    << "\n" << "Damn you should go to school dude." << endl;
}
};
template <>
class Cmplx<char>
{
public:
Cmplx<string> tmp;
};

template <typename type>
long double abs(Cmplx<type> param)
{
    long double tmp;
    tmp=sqrt(pow(param.Re,2)+pow(param.Im,2));
    return tmp;
}
template <typename type>
long double arg(Cmplx<type> param)
{
    return atan2(param.Im,param.Re);
}
template <typename type>
Cmplx<long double> exp(Cmplx <type> param)
{
    Cmplx<long double> tmp, exim(cos(param.Im),sin(param.Im));
    tmp=exp(param.Re)*exim;
    return tmp;
}
template <typename type>
Cmplx <long double> log(Cmplx<type> param)
{
    Cmplx<long double> IArg(0,arg(param));
    return IArg+log(abs(param));
}
template <typename type, typename paramT>
Cmplx<long double> log_b(Cmplx<type> arg, paramT param)
{
    return log(arg)/log(param);
}
```

An implementation of that class:

```
#include"cmplx oper.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Cmplx<long double> A(2,3);
cout << log(A);
getch();
return true;
}
```

The result is: `1.28247+0i`
But it was supposed to be `1.28247+0.98279i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually want to pass the method itself - you want to call the method and pass the returned value into the constructor. That's exactly what you're doing here, and it should be fine. In other words, what you've got is already broadly equivalent to:

```
Cmplx<long double> log()
{
    long double tmp = arg();
    Cmplx<long double> IArg(0, tmp);
    return IArg + log(abs());
}
```

I suspect that something else is going wrong - such as your object not having the data you think it does to start with. I suggest you step through the code in a debugger, add some diagnostic logging, or add some unit tests to validate this class and then whatever's using it.

(As an aside, it looks odd to me to use Pascal-case for the variables like this. I haven't seen any C++ conventions which do that...)

EDIT: I suspect this is the problem:

```
friend Cmplx operator +(vartype const param, Cmplx const para)
{
    Cmplx Tmp;
    Tmp.Re=para.Re+param;
    return Tmp;
}
```

Notice how you never use any part of `para` other than `para.Re`, and never assign to `Tmp.Im` at all. I suspect you want:

```
friend Cmplx operator +(vartype const param, Cmplx const para)
{
    Cmplx Tmp = para;
    Tmp.Re += param;
    return Tmp;
}
```

or possibly just:

```
friend Cmplx operator +(vartype const param, Cmplx const para)
{
    return Cmplx(para.Re + param, para.Im);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know very well how to use a debugger, but I tried calling the `arg()` method itself, It gives me what is supposed to give.

Comment: @Juan: I'd invest some time in learning how to use a debugger for one thing then. But if `arg()` does the right thing, then you should check what your + operator does...

Comment: I think that the operator is not the problem, since it is able to assign a number to the `Re` part of the number, actually the natural logarithm of the absolute value of `*this` that would be written in code as [`log(abs(*this))`]

Comment: @Juan: Well, you don't know where the problem *is* at the moment, so don't discount anything. If you don't want to use a debugger, then pepper your code with "print" statements so you can see what's going on at every step that's involved in `log()`. Do you have a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? If so, that would certainly help.

Comment: @Juan: See my edit... although I'm not sure that's even the operator being called. I'd have expected to see `operator +(Cmplx const para, vartype const param)`. Maybe C++ assumes it can switch the parameters round - I'm far from an expert in C++.

Comment: @Jon: that last operator does the same thing as `Cmplx operator +(vartype param)` but for the inverse order, so I can put `<vartype>+Cmplx` or `Cmplx+<vartype>` indistinctly and I wanted to sum up only the `Re` variable of my `Cmplx`, the `Im` variable is untouched.
Also that's the reason of the output, it was able to sum the `Re` part, but not to assign the `arg()` to `Im` since the beginning.

Comment: @Juan: It's not leaving `Im` untouched - it's leaving it as 0. Look at the code you gave - *nothing is assigning a value to `Tmp.Im`*. Have you tried my suggested fix? I readily admit to not knowing much about C++ operators, but the code you've got there looks wrong - and it looks like it'll misbehave in exactly the way you're seeing, giving a 0 value for `Im` because you never *give* it a value.

Comment: @Juan: (In particular, I'm confused about which operators are able to use "this" object and which aren't. This is a lot simpler in C# where operators always have to be static... Even so, my guess certainly explains the behaviour you're seeing.)

Comment: @Jon: Ok, got it, trying it now, I got a good feeling about this.
Thanks, a lot.

Comment: @Jon: Solved, you were right.
My logic was a bit messed on this thing.
Thank you very much, now I'll be able to sleep comfortably ;).